# Cómo usar las claves foráneas en un programa de registro de usuarios en Java con MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo dos tablas en mi base de datos, una tiene una clave foránea con la otra.

Tablas con clave foránea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Interfaz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el JComboBox "Perfil" tengo:

1. --Seleccionar--
2. Portero
3. Administrador

Entonces, al momento de guardar los datos de los textfield en la tabla, qué hago con el "Perfil", sabiendo que el ID de Portero es 1 y el ID de Administrador es 2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dependiendo del Perfil, la persona tendrá ciertos botones habilitados o no. Al ser mi primera vez con claves foráneas, no se cómo proseguir ahora con esto.

Guardo el Index del JComboBox Perfil en una variable "id_perfil":

```
dato_usuarios.setId_perfil(cboPerfil.getSelectedIndex());
```

Código para agregar un usuario nuevo a la tabla:

```
public boolean agregar(Dato_usuarios d_usr) {
        sSQL =  "INSERT INTO usuarios"
                + "(id_usuario, nombre, apellido, usuario, contrasena, id_perfil)"
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        boolean resultado;

        // Java 7 try-with-resources
        try (PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sSQL)) {

            // pstm.setInt(1, d_usr.getId_perfil()); no es necesario en este método
            pstm.setString(2, d_usr.getNombre());
            pstm.setString(3, d_usr.getApellido());
            pstm.setString(4, d_usr.getUsuario());
            pstm.setString(5, d_usr.getContrasena());
            pstm.setInt(6, d_usr.getId_perfil());
            pstm.executeUpdate();

            resultado = true;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            resultado = false;
            }

        return resultado;
    }
```

1. Qué debo hacer para que se le asigne el nombre del Perfil
   seleccionado, estoy muy perdido.
2. Al mostrar un usuario existente, cómo muestro el ID del usuario en
   el textfield y el ID del Perfil en el JComboBox?.
3. Cómo puedo saber si un usuario es Portero o Administrador para luego
   habilitarle o no ciertos botones?.

Es mi primera vez haciendo esto, espero puedan guiarme un poco aquí, gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como pídes una guía te voy a indicar los pasos que deberías seguir pero sin detallar nada porque lo que pides es muy extenso y no creo que se adapte al formato de este foro. Depués de que hayas practicado por tu cuenta, si te encuentras un problema concreto puedes hacer una pregunta más concisa.

1.- Debes recuperar todos los datos que necesites tratar. Lo harás con una consulta que una las tablas "usuarios" y "perfiles" por el `id_perfil` y con los datos que te devuelva la consulta podrás crear un objeto que los encapsule y los maneje de una forma más cómoda. En ese objeto que podemos llamar del tipo `Usuario` contendrás todos los datos de las dos tablas que necesites y harás los metodos `get` y `set` para los atributos que necesites. Con esto solucionamos tu primera pregunta.

Un ejemplo de sentencia SQL para tu ejemplo sería:

```
SELECT usuarios.*, perfiles.nombre
FROM perfiles INNER JOIN usuarios ON perfiles.id_perfil = usuarios.id_perfil;
```

2.- Con una lista de `Usuario` creada anteriormente cargarás el Combobox [según la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) y, según tambien la documentación, harás un render para que te muestre el objeto como necesites. Con esto solucionamos tu segunda pregunta.

3.- Para el resto de la aplicación y sabiendo cuál es tu `Usuario` logeado, podrás crear el resto de ventanas conforme el nivel de permiso que tenga. Así cuando hagas el método para crear las ventanas, rellenarás sólo los componentes a los que tenga acceso. Puedes también crearte componentes personalizados para agrupar controles que vayas a reutilizar y luego rellenar las distintas ventanas con ellos. La forma "cutre" sería hacer una ventana tipo "Administrador" y otra ventana tipo "Portero" y llamar a una u otra según sea, pero reutilizarías mucho menos código y si tuvieras que cambiar algo tendrías que hacerlo en varios sitios, así que no es recomendable. Con esto se responde tu tercera pregunta.

Espero que con estos pasos puedas seguir puliendo su aplicación.

Comment: ya veo, al menos ya tengo una idea. Una pregunta, cómo sería una sentencia SQL para pedir id de ambas tablas?, nunca lo había hecho antes...

Comment: He añadido un ejemplo de la sentencia que pides a la respuesta.

Comment: ya veo, entiendo. Pero, de esta forma es que se trabajan las claves foraneas? halando de ambas tablas?, yo pensé que se halaba automáticamente jeje

Comment: Las claves foráneas sirven para enlazar tablas que referencian la clave con una fila de otra tabla. Podrían ser claves múltiples que abarcaran más de un registro, o estar relacionadas mediante claves intermedias. Eso depende de cómo hayas modelado tus tablas. Tu ejemplo es el más sencillo.